# How to replace special characters and then break line in oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, split, oracle12c

This is how I am getting result in Oracle 12c

| Id | Date Range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "2019-01-07","2019-02-17","2019-03-17"] |

And I want it

| Id | Date Range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-07 |
| 1 | 2019-02-17 |
| 1 | 2019-03-17 |

I tried replace function but it works either at the beginning or at end
I want to remove [ ] and "

Comment: Do you need to return a row for each date in the date input string? Or one row with a newline in the resulting column? Should the `Date Range`column in the result be of type date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Oracle version is 12, you can use JSON functions on your current output to get the desired output. Your current output is a valid JSON array of strings, all you need to do is to extract them. Something like this:

```
with
  current_output (id, date_range) as (
    select 1, '["2019-01-07","2019-02-17","2019-03-17"]' from dual
  )
select co.id, t.date_range
from   current_output co
       cross apply
       json_table(co.date_range, '$[*]' columns date_range path '$') t
;

ID DATE_RANGE     
-- ---------------
 1 2019-01-07     
 1 2019-02-17     
 1 2019-03-17
```

Comment: When I add a new column like Date Range1 along with Date Range the result is coming up as a cartesian product. Is there anything I can remove the cartesian product?

Comment: @swanandkulkarni - Not sure what you mean. I understand that you add one more column, similar to the one you have. What is the desired output though? And what query are you using that gives you a cartesian product? Surely you modified the query - the one I wrote doesn't even touch that other column.