# Oracle 12c Json split

Tags: sql, json, oracle

This is how I am getting result in Oracle 12c

| Id | Start Date Range | End Date Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "2019-01-07","2019-02-17","2019-03-17"] | [ "2019-01-14","2019-02-21","2019-03-21"] |

And I want it

| Id | Start Date Range | End Date Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-14 |
| 1 | 2019-02-17 | 2019-02-21 |
| 1 | 2019-03-17 | 2019-03-21 |

Earlier I had asked this question for single-column split and below is the link
[How to replace special characters and then break line in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061162/how-to-replace-special-characters-and-then-break-line-in-oracle/67061565#67061565)
But when I add another column there is the cartesian product.

Comment: Presumably the first end-date being 2019-01-07 rather than 2019-01-14 is a typo?

Comment: There is something wrong with the data model itself though. How do you ensure, for example, that the two arrays in the two columns (in the same row) have the same number of elements? The data should be structured so that you get a single array, consisting of objects with two members: start date and end date. Then the query to extract the data would also be much simpler. Do you have any control over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_table` to extract the strings from the JSON arrays, presumably as actual dates:

```
select t.id, s.n, s.start_date, e.end_date
from your_table t
cross apply json_table (
  t.start_range, '$[*]'
  columns
    n for ordinality,
    start_date date path '$'
) s
join json_table (
  t.end_range, '$[*]' 
  columns
    n for ordinality,
    end_date date path '$'
) e
on e.n = s.n
```

The `for ordinality` clauses provide an index into each array, and the join then matches up the 'related' array entries.

```
ID |  N | START_DATE | END_DATE 
-: | -: | :--------- | :--------
 1 |  1 | 07-JAN-19  | 14-JAN-19
 1 |  2 | 17-FEB-19  | 21-FEB-19
 1 |  3 | 17-MAR-19  | 21-MAR-19
```

If you want string rather than dates for some reason you can just change the data type in the column clauses.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4810d05975dbcca4fd7e7e6badfec153)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `regexp_substr` and `connect by` after replacing `[`,`]` and `"` with empty spaces.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table testtable(Id int, Start_Date_Range varchar(500),  End_Date_Range varchar(500));

 insert into testtable values(1 ,'[ "2019-01-07","2019-02-17","2019-03-17"]',   '[ "2019-01-14","2019-02-21","2019-03-21"]');
```

Query:

```
 select distinct id, trim(regexp_substr(replace(replace(replace(Start_Date_Range,'"',''),'[',''),']',''),'[^,]+', 1, level) ) Start_Date_Range,
  trim(regexp_substr(replace(replace(replace(end_Date_Range,'"',''),'[',''),']',''),'[^,]+', 1, level) ) End_Date_Range,
  level
   from testtable
    connect by regexp_substr(Start_Date_Range, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
    order by id, level;
```

Output:

| ID | START_DATE_RANGE | END_DATE_RANGE | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-14 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019-02-17 | 2019-02-21 | 2 |
| 1 | 2019-03-17 | 2019-03-21 | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc9dc92aa70f7fa73a99f06196dc6f0f)*

Comment: JSON data should only be processed with JSON functions. You can turn screws with a knife, but that doesn't make it a reasonable practice (unless a screwdriver is not available; in this context, that would mean "in Oracle 11.2 and lower", when JSON functions weren't available). The OP said Oracle 12c a few times, so he does have a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to the OP, I pointed out that the data model is not quite right. The values in the two JSON arrays are related; such data should be encoded in a single object, not two. There should be a single array of objects, each object having two members: start date and end date.

To illustrate the data model I am suggesting, I start with a sample input table (with an additional id), I use Alex Poole's answer exactly as is to generate the table the OP asked about, but then I follow that with JSON generating functions to put the data back into JSON format to illustrate how I think the input data should look like. (The provider of the JSON string should create a JSON in this format, rather than sending two separate JSON arrays of strings representing dates).

What I do not show here is how to use a single call to `JSON_TABLE` to split the data from the single array of objects created at the end of my query. That is a lot simpler than the query to get data out of two separate JSON arrays.

NOTE - this is not really an answer; I wrote it as an answer because it obviously wouldn't fit in a comment.

```
with
  t (id, start_date_range, end_date_range) as (
    select 1, '["2019-01-07","2019-02-17","2019-03-17"]',
              '["2019-01-14","2019-02-21","2019-03-21"]' from dual union all
    select 5, '["2020-04-23","2020-06-15"]',
              '["2020-04-30","2020-06-19"]'              from dual
  )
, shown_as_table(id, n, start_date, end_date) as (
    select t.id, s.n, to_char(s.start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                      to_char(e.end_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    from t
    cross apply json_table (
      t.start_date_range, '$[*]'
      columns
        n for ordinality,
        start_date date path '$'
    ) s
    join json_table (
      t.end_date_range, '$[*]' 
      columns
        n for ordinality,
        end_date date path '$'
    ) e
    on e.n = s.n
  )
select id, json_arrayagg(
                json_object('start' value start_date, 'end' value end_date)
                format json
                order by n
           ) as date_range_array
from   shown_as_table
group  by id
;
```

Output:

```
ID DATE_RANGE_ARRAY                                                                                                               
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 [{"start":"2019-01-07","end":"2019-01-14"},{"start":"2019-02-17","end":"2019-02-21"},{"start":"2019-03-17","end":"2019-03-21"}]                                 
 5 [{"start":"2020-04-23","end":"2020-04-30"},{"start":"2020-06-15","end":"2020-06-19"}]
```